# Jquery Mobile and AJAX Link conflict

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

Hi I'm currently developping an app using Jquery mobile, now I want to save some feedback from my users using Ajax. The problem is (I think) that my Ajax conflicts with the jquery mobile framework. Because my Ajax call etc only works the second time I load my page?

Any idea's of how to solve this annoying problem?

Thanks in advance